# Want to push Google Reviews onto Website Seamlessly and In real time to Add business value

Tags: web, google-my-business-api

Basically looking for recommendation and best practices for pushing reviews from Google My business profiles onto Websites, dynamically.

Has someone implemented this and could someone provide adequate guidelines for this?

HAppy to answer any questions and discuss.

Answer (score 0):

As cited [here](https://support.google.com/business/thread/1858306?hl=en&msgid=1858311):

> Google does not, as yet, provide a widget for displaying reviews.
> That said, they do provide access to that information via the API.
> https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data   There
> are developers who have created plugins or blocks of code that handle
> that for you.  The range of functionality varies, so it will take a
> little bit of research.

Answer (score 0):

Many third parties offer widgets, even I wrote some @ free usage; you can generate it right on reviewsmaker.com if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 parameters to get your business information.

1-APIKEY
2-Place ID

Find Place ID from here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details?hl=en_US#json

```
<?php

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=API_KEY&place_id=blabla";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);


$res        = json_decode($result,true);


$reviews    = $res['result']['reviews'];

print_r($reviews);


?
```